# Can I use Laplace transform to calculate cos(at+b) with displacement theorem?

Tags: laplace-transform

So I'm just learning Laplace transform in college, and an exercise asked us to solve this:

$cos(at+b)$

Now, I found multiple answers saying that this evaluates to:

$\LARGE \frac{s * cos(b) - a * sin(b)}{s^2+a^2}$

using the well-known formula of $cos(a + b)$.

But here comes my question. Can we actually use the displacement theorem to solve this?

What I mean is rewrite $cos(at+b)$ as $cos(a(t+\frac{b}{a}))$ and then use the theorem as:

$L[f(t-c)] = e^{-cs}*L[f(t)] = e^{-cs} * F(s)$

Using this, I arrive at:

$\LARGE L[f(t)] = \frac{e^{\frac{bs}{a}}*s}{s^2+a^2}$

Which doesn't really look like the answer above. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case you have the Heaviside function.

So that if you inverse the function you get:
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}} \left \{e^{bs/a}\dfrac s {s^2+a^2} \right \}=U(t+\frac ba)\cos (a (t+\dfrac b a ))$$
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}} \left \{e^{bs/a}\dfrac s {s^2+a^2} \right \}=U(t+\frac ba)\cos (at +b))$$

For the first case you have the Laplace transform of:
$$\mathcal {L} \left \{u(t)\cos (at+ b ) \right \}$$

Comment: So the difference is that in my approach I must have $t > - b / a$, otherwise the Laplace transform doesn't work?

Comment: Yes that's the difference the Heaviside function is not the same. @AlexGh

Comment: Yes with your approach  it's $\cos (at+b)$ for $t \ge -b/a$ and $0$ elsewhere @AlexGh